# Can't boot to Gentoo from grub shell

Tags: boot, grub, gentoo

I tried to install Gentoo for the first time.

I created /dev/sda3 for /boot and /dev/sda4 for /.

I compiled the genkernel and generate the initramfs file successfully.

After installing grub, I reboot the machine. Then the machine boot in grub shell. I found [this link](http://www.chrissearle.org/node/322), and followed the instruction step by step.

Firstly, I executed "root=(hd0,2)"

Then I executed "kernel=/kernel-genkernel.... root=/dev/sda4 ro"

Then I executed "initrd=/initramfs..."

Then I executed ”boot"

The kernel was boot then when mounting root, it reported an error "your real /dev is missing files required to boot"

What does it mean? What should I do in the next step? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should always read what the Gentoo Handbook says. This is the official reference.

An example of grub config given by the Handbook for genkernel users is given [here](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=1&chap=10#doc_chap2_pre4).

What we can see is that the current initrams expects a `real_root` attribute to be given to the kernel command-line, so it can mount/chroot/etc correctly the so-called 'real root' which is your actual `'/'` mount point.

So I would first try the following grub commands:

```
root (hd0,2)
kernel /kernel-genkernel [...] real_root=/dev/sda4 ro
initrd /initramfs [...]
boot
```